# Retina display problem - GUI Java applications display fix

Tags: java, display, eclipse

On my MacBook with retina when I open Java GUI applications with Oracle Java Se 7 (JEdit, Eclipse) I encountered the same display issue (font antialiasing an overal GUI with very bad resolution).

```
$ /usr/libexec/java_home --verbose
Matching Java Virtual Machines (5):
    1.7.0_75, x86_64:   "Java SE 7" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, x86_64: "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.6.0_65-b14-466.1, i386:   "Java SE 6" /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
```

In order to fix this I'd applied an workaround according to the following

> Fixing Steps

1. Drag affected application from Applications to Desktop (Ex. YourApp.app)
2. Edit /Applications/YourApp.app/Contents/Info.plist with your favorite text editor;
3. At the end of the file add the next two lines, before the end tags `</dict></plist>` and save file;

   ```
   <key>NSHighResolutionCapable</key>
   <true/>
   ```
4. Start YourApp.app from desktop and see if it fixed;
5. If fixed, drag YourApp.app back to /Applications and retest.

> Fix for: JEdit, Eclipse etc.

Workaround source:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972#c4

Why this appear under Oracle Java SE 7 but on the older Apple Java SE 6 not ?

Comment: This is a Q&A site so it's kind of important of keeping questions and answers separated. Can you please revise your question to actually focus on the problem you are trying to solve, wait for it to get reopened and than add the answer below?

Comment: Apple's Java is old and predates Retina and they have not added it would seem to be the obvious answer

Comment: Yes but with Apple Java SE 6 older version works well and in newer Oracle Java SE 7 is not. Additional feedback is welcome.